# Sails Waterline Sync calling

Tags: sails.js, waterline

How can I call a Waterline function synchronously using Sails.js. I tried

```
var data = Model.findOne({ foo : "bar"});
```

and

```
sync(Model, findOne);
sync.fiber(function(){
    var data = Model.findOne({ foo : "bar"});
});
```

None of them worked for me.

What is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Waterline methods are asynchronous, plain and simple.  No command will make them otherwise.   You'll find this is the case for many Node methods that access external data sources (database, HTTP, etc.)

If you need to chain them in a more synchronous-feeling way, you can use a package like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is possible for waterline. And I'm almost certain it's not the intention.

```
Model.findOne({ foo : "bar"}, function(err, result){
  var data = result;
});
```

The above would be better....don't fight the asynchronous nature of nodejs. It will only hurt later.

Comment: But why? Is there any benefit?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry this answer is too late, you probably had found a solution by now, but for future references, here it is
you may need to make the lodash global by updating /config/globals.js and set `_: true`
then you will edit the /config/bootstrap.js with the following

```
global.sync = require("synchronize");
_.each(sails.models,function(model){
    _.map(model,function(attrValue,attrKey){ 
        if(typeof attrValue=="function"){
            model[attrKey+"Sync"]=sync(attrValue);
        }
    });
});
```

from here on you can use a synchronous version of any model function by appending "Sync" after the function like this `users.findSync({fname:'Mostafa'})`

Comment: Your solution seems good. But we also need to add the exec function. .exec(function (err, found) . How to do it sync? 

If I use your method and findSync, the object returned has always the property values empty.